# After closing the application, the app stays on the background process in c#

Tags: c#

The app remains on the background after exit.

When I press the X button to close the form, the application is still running in the background. I have to manually kill it from the task manager. I think the reason behind this is because the TCP Client is still open? below is my code.

I already added Form1_FormClosing to close the form on exit, but that didn't help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace Telnet2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Thread _readWriteThread;
        private TcpClient _client;
        private NetworkStream _networkStream;

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const string hostname = "192.168.1.111";
            const int port = 23;
            ServerSocket(hostname, port);
        }
        public void ServerSocket(string ip, int port)
        {
            try
            {
                _client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
                MessageBox.Show(@"You have succesfully connect to the server");
                lblConnection.Text = @"Connected to the server " + ip + ".";
                txtBoxBarcodeDisplay.Show();
                lblTelnetResponse.Show();
                lblConnection.Hide();
                btnConnect.Text = "Connected";
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Failed to connect to server");
                return;
            }

            // Assign networkstream
            _networkStream = _client.GetStream();

            // Start socket read/write thread
            _readWriteThread = new Thread(ReadWrite);
            _readWriteThread.Start();
        }
        private void ReadWrite()
        {
            var received = "";

            //Read first thing givent o us
            received = Read();
            //Console.WriteLine(received);
            if (!received.Contains("HB"))
                txtBoxBarcodeDisplay.Text = received + Environment.NewLine;


            //txt_BarcodeDisplay.Text = recieved.ToString();


            //Set up connection loop
            while (true)
            {
                //var command = btn_StopConnection.Text;
                //if (command == "STOP1")
                //    break;

                //write(command);
                received = Read();
                //Console.WriteLine(received);
                if (!received.Contains("HB"))
                    txtBoxBarcodeDisplay.Text += received + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            // possible method to end the port connection
        }

        public string Read()
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            var received = "";

            var size = _networkStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            received = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, size);

            return received;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're starting a thread, but it isn't a background thread.  Background threads won't stay up when the application wants to exit.  For more information on this idea: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/foreground-and-background-threads

Comment: You should be using `async/await` anyway

Comment: Make sense thank you @Amy.
To whoever encounter this problem, I solved it by making the thread isBackground = true...

_readWriteThread.IsBackground = true;